# Using jmeter to perform login

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

In my login form there is a

**button class**

**Here is the code**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-3" id="loginbtn">Log in</button>
```

How to add parameter values for this?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't really click buttons so there is no sense in posting this limited HTML code here.

JMeter acts on [HTTP protocol basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview), it sends [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods), waits for responses and measures time in-between.

So in order to perform the login using JMeter you need to send the same requests as real browser does. The easiest way to capture the requests is using JMeter [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) - this way you will be able to do what you want in the browser and JMeter will record the associated requests into [Recording Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller) so you will be later be able to replay (or attempt to replay) the requests.

The fastest and the easiest way of preparing JMeter for recording is using [JMeter Templates Feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)

1. From JMeter's Main Menu choose `File - Templates - Recording` and click "Create"

   [image: JMeter Templates Recording]
2. Select HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click "Start".
3. Configure your browser to use JMeter as a proxy:

   [image: JMeter Firefox Proxy]
4. Navigate to the web page in the browser - Jmeter should capture it under `Thread Group - Recording Controller`

   [image: JMeter Record HTTP Request]